# Heyzap mediation with latest Facebook Audience SDK

Tags: facebook-audience-network, mobile-ad-mediation, heyzap

Following Heyzap mediation integration for SDK 10 & Facebook Audience Network, and I have noticed they use these two lines in `build.gradle`:

```
//facebook
compile 'com.fyber.mediation:facebook:4.10.0-r4@aar'
compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.10.0'
```

I'm using latest Audience Network sdk. Its version is 4.15. Does this mean the mediation won't work?

Must the mediation lib be the same version that the facebook sdk to work?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version recommended on our docs is the version that we have tested and confirmed works with our mediation - we periodically update our adapters for each mediated network as changes come out. If there is an issue with that version you need resolved with a newer version of the Facebook SDK, you can always try it, but either way contact support@heyzap.com and we can look into it too!

source: I'm a Heyzap engineer

Comment: to answer specifically: it may or may not work if you use a newer Audience Network SDK with an older mediation adapter library. Mostly it's just untested, but if Facebook's API changes, our adapter has to also.

Comment: I see thanks. i will try first to see if it works. How would I know if it is not working?

Comment: SDK 10 comes with a mediation test suite, which will help you test ads from FAN. It will also show you whether or not the SDK is detected. Try that and see if it helps?